# Where to set magento store name

Tags: magento

Where in magento admin do I set the store name so that the transactional email can call it with:

```
{{var store.getFrontendName()}}
```

I've already tried system > config > general > general > store info > store name

Thanks

Comment: You are in the correct part of the backend - have you checked under the store scope?

Answer (score 0):

To get the store name, use this variable:

```
{{config path="general/store_information/name"}}
```

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value for `store.getFrontendName()` in the admin under System->Manage Stores

Answer (score 0):

Store -> All Stores -> General -> General -> Store Information -> Store Name